# How does one use Magento's REST API to run keyword queries?

Tags: magento, rest, search

I'm developing a community extension for Magento, when a product search is detected, some JavaScript included with the extension needs to query the Magento API to get a larger number of results than are rendered on page.

I have the API configured, responding, and returning useful data, but I'm struggling to find a way to apply a query to the API call. I've tried adding `?q=` or `?keyword=` and similar, but it continues to return the same set of data without any filtering applied. Countless passes through Google, Magento StackExchange, and various Magento developer forums haven't made it clear one way or another if this is even possible.

Does the REST API support keyword / phrase searches, or will my extension need to include a block that adds this functionality to the REST API?

Comment: What api method are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at [Magento API Filtering](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/get_filters.html) .

You could also create you own [Custom API or Extending the Core API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html)